# how to evaluate Gaussian Process regressor

Tags: bayesian, gaussian-process, hyperparameter

I am trying to do a blackbox hyper-parameter optimization with GPR. To achieve I use GPR with Matern core with sklearn. Now I hope to know whether it fitted well, or whether it is over-fitted or under-fitted. Is there any way to do that evaluation? Also I use `EI(expected improvement )` as acquisition function. Is it meaningful to compare the EI value round by round, then I could say it get better? (personally, I don't support this idea.)